# Trusty 14.04.4 Laptop powers off unexpectedly

Tags: 14.04, power-management

Recently upgraded the HWE to the Wily stack (Kernel 4.2) on my Thinkpad T410. Now, even when on AC, the laptop powers down for no reason.  Originally I thought it was due to inactivity and suspected tlp, but there doesn't seem to be any settings for "power down when inactive."  Also, this happened while I was actually using the laptop.  This never happened on the 14.04.3 and Vivid stack.

I have a desktop system that is also running the same level of software and it remains active all the time.  The desktop system does use a proprietary driver for the NIC, but is otherwise all open source like the laptop.  I also run Apache, sftp and Steam on the desktop system but not on the laptop.

Any ideas on what I should be checking?

Comment: It might be over-heating and powering off automatically to prevent internal damage

Comment: That would appear to be the issue.  When I shut down BOINC the temperature drops drastically and it no longer shuts down.  This wasn't an issue with the older 3.xx kernel so I'm wondering if it's an issue with the new 4.2 kernel?  The desktop system (with an AMD CPU) doesn't run nearly as hot under the same conditions, but there is also a lot more room for air circulation and the CPU has that BIG honkin' fan on it.  I'll have to see if there's any way to "tune down" BOINC so it doesn't run as hot.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Adjusted BOINC to run 75% so it is only using three cores instead of all four and that has resolved the issue.